# Kotlin List<T> contains objects from types other than T

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting, type-conversion

I am doing a Kotlin exercise, in which I needed convert an input list coming from a file into Longs. 
I made what I thought was a neat function to convert that input from a List of Strings to a List of whatever type I needed, and if it couldn't cast the input, just ignore it basically.

What I ended up with was a List with String objects, and I have no idea how this could happen.
Can anyone explain me how can this be possible and how to make the actual idealized function work?

Here is the function:

```
    fun <T: Any> readInputIntoList(fileName: String): List<T> {
        return File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName).toURI())
            .readLines()
            .mapNotNull { it as T}
    }
```

Here is a simple test code I used:

```
    val input = Utils.readInputIntoList<Long>("input.txt")
    print(input[0] is Long)
```

This prints "false".

contents of the file could be something like this:

```
123457
98952
65241
62222
144922
```

Comment: `in Java I believe that the compiler would try to convert those Strings into number values` No it wouldn't.  Call `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: True, just checked it in the meanwhile.
Anyway, something should happen in Kotlin other than ending up with a List<Long> filled with String objects I think... or at least I need help understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt already answered your question, I am adding my answer to give some code examples.

Due to type erasure the runtime can't know the actual type of T when invoking your function. Hence the cast actually does nothing and any code using the result will have to deal with the problems.
Once using a member function of type Long there will be a ClassCastException.

```
val input = Utils.readInputIntoList<Long>("input.txt")
print(input[0].div(1))
```

To actually cast within the function, you will have to pass in the KClass, so the runtime knows what that class is.

```
fun <T: Any> readInputIntoList(inputValues: List<String>, kclass: KClass<T>): List<T> =  
inputValues.map { kclass.cast(it) }
```

Then the function invocation will already throw an Exception.

```
val input = readInputIntoList(listOf("1234", "21345"), Long::class)
```

Back to your actual problem: You would want to use String.toLongOrNull() instead of casting anyway. So your function would look like this:

```
fun <T: Any> readInputIntoList(inputValues: List<String>, f: (String) -> T?): List<T> =
    inputValues.mapNotNull(f)
```

And would be invoked like this:

```
val input = readInputIntoList(listOf("1234", "21345"), String::toLongOrNull)
```

Comment: Kotlin has `s.toLongOrNull()`.

Comment: Thank you. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a type cast like `it as T` in Kotin or `(T)it` in Java, it's your responsibility to make sure that the object is the type you say it is, or a `ClassCastException` will result.

Normally, it will happen right away, but in this case you are casting to a generic type parameter.  Java/Kotlin implement generics with type erasure.  That means that there is only *one* implementation of your your method.  `readInputIntoList<String>` and `readInputIntoList<Long>` will do exactly the same thing when you pass them the same (actual) parameters, because it's the *same code*.

The type `T` is not a parameter to the method, so this method can't actually check to ensure that `it` is of the right type.  It just assumes that you know what you're doing, and the cast has no effect at all.  If it turns out to be the wrong type, then a `ClassCastException` will usually occur when someone tries to use the list contents.

Comment: A caveat is that you can use `inline fun <reified T> ...` and get different code depending on `T`. Of course it won't help in this particular instance because the conversion needed isn't a cast.

Comment: The way I like to put it is: **A cast doesn't _convert_ a value to the required type; a cast promises the compiler that it's _already_ the required type.**  — In my experience, casts are very rarely needed in well-written code (mainly when interacting with data from a framework or other external source).